# Obtener el valor de un <label> mediante su ID con Javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Estoy intentando obtener el valor de un `<label>` mediante su `id` sin embargo no es posible recuperar este valor para almacenarlo en una variable para luego pasar esta variable a otro archivo `.html` .

**Contexto**

El `<label>` obtiene su valor a traves de una variable mediante el `document.getElementById('LABEL').innerHTML` desde un archivo `.js`, si embargo requiero obtener el valor de este `ID` una vez que se le asigna uno; este valor quiero obtenerlo en mi `paginaHTML1` para enviarlo a `paginaHTML2`.

**Lo que he intentado**

Asigno el valor a mi `<label>`, obtener el valor en `pagina1` y luego enviarlo por `sessionStorage` a `pagina2`.

**Archivo .JS**

```
let variable1=1001001;
document.getElementById('LABEL').innerHTML = variable1;
```

**Archivo paginaHTML1**

```
<script>
  let valorDemiLabel= document.getElementById('LABEL').innerHTML;
  sessionStorage.setItem("valorDemiLabel", valorDemiLabel);
</script>
```

**Archivo paginaHTML2**

```
<script>
   let valorDemiLabel= sessionStorage.getItem("valorDemiLabel");
   console.log(valorDemiLabel);
</script>
```

**Informacion Extra**

Si envio por `sessionStorage` la variable de forma bruta `let valorDemiLabel= 100100;` en lugar del `let valorDemiLabel= document.getElementById('LABEL').innerHTML;` todo funciona bien y la variable es recibida correctamente en mi otro archivo.

Por lo que creo que el problema esta a la hora de obtener el valor del mi `<label>` entonces he intentado obtener el valor con `.innerText` y con `.textContent` pero aun asi es inutil y el resultado es el mismo si mando a imprimir a consola la variable en mi misma `pagina1` no obtengo absolutamente nada, ni error ni nada.

Alguien me ayuda a entender que pasa y agradecere cualquier comentario.